# Undefined index when I try to get a value from a select tag in HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, select

I'm trying to get a value from a select tag in html using PHP but it keeps saying that the index is undefined.

My HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="proceso.php">
  <label for="language">Idioma</label>
  <select id="language" name="prueba">
    <option value="es_LA">Español</option>
    <option value="en_US">English</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <label for="username">Nombre de usuario</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  <br>
  <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  <br>
  <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <br>
  <label for="genderM">Masculino</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderM" value="M">
  <label for="genderF">Femenino</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderF" value="F">
  <label for="genderO">Otro</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderO" value="O">
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

And this is how I'm trying to get the value in my procesos.php file:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO account(username,userpass,email,gender) VALUES('$_POST[prueba],'$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]',$_POST[email]',$_POST[gender]')";
```

The error says: Notice: Undefined index: prueba

Comment: I know I have and undefined column in my $sql, but the problem persists even adding it.

Comment: check your quotes, the command is not properly formatted. If you are unsure, `echo($sql)` to see whether it is fine, try this: `$sql = "INSERT INTO account(username,userpass,email,gender) VALUES('".$_POST["prueba"]."','".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["gender"]."')";`

Comment: Just tried your code and gave me the same error. Even if I comment the $sql sentence and try to get the value in a normal var, it says that the index is undefined

Comment: warning your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I know it. I'm just testing my database to see if everything works ok >-<

Comment: what do you get if you `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: you have store & insert the value of $_POST['prueba']; in database? & but u are accepting 4 variable but you are passing 5 in insert query, why?

Comment: I don't know why but it's working now... with the same code I posted first.

Comment: @MohitKumar The answer to your question is in the first comment. The problem is solved now, I didn't do anything, it just started working lol

Answer (score 0):

On "INSERT INTO account(username,userpass,email,gender)" Here you are accepting 4 variable but you are passing '$_POST[prueba]','$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[gender]' Five to the query

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I'm not querying my database, just getting the values in the sentence. Even if I try to get the value in a normal var like $var = $_POST['prueba']; it keeps saying undefined index

Comment: No... I will get an error like "the values you're trying to insert don't match the defined columns' If I try to query it, but I'm not doing it. Just getting the value on the sentence. Like I told you, if I comment the $sql sentence and try to save the value in a normal var, it keeps saying the 'undefined index' error.

Comment: Obviously it will show that..because the values are not set than..Just use isset function...and its done

Comment: use this  if(isset($_POST['prueba']))
{
 $prueba = $_POST['prueba'];
} than use $prueba  variable